# MapPolyline locations binding - Windows Store App

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, windows-store-apps, bing-maps

I've got a problem with binding my LocationCollection to MapPolyline locations property.
This is fragment of my XAML code:

```
<bm:Map x:Name="map" Credentials="MY_KEY" Grid.Column="1">
    <bm:Map.Children>
        <bm:MapItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PushPinTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding HostsList}"/>
    </bm:Map.Children>
    <bm:Map.ShapeLayers>
        <bm:MapShapeLayer>
            <bm:MapShapeLayer.Shapes>
                <bm:MapPolyline Locations="{Binding PathLocations}" Color="Red" Width="5" />
            </bm:MapShapeLayer.Shapes>
        </bm:MapShapeLayer>
    </bm:Map.ShapeLayers>
</bm:Map>
```

And ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<HostDetailsModel> HostsList { get; set; }
private LocationCollection pathLocations;
public LocationCollection PathLocations 
{
   get { return pathLocations; }
   set { SetProperty(ref pathLocations, value); }
}

public TracePageViewModel()
{
    HostsList = new ObservableCollection<HostDetailsModel>();
    PathLocations = new LocationCollection();
    ....
}
....
```

When I'm launching the app I've got a XamlParseException in my page constructor on line

```
this.InitializeComponent();
```

Without the content between the `<bm:Map.ShapeLayers>...</bm:Map.ShapeLayers>` everything is fine. 
Pushpins are binded correctly.
Does anyone know what is going on?
Thanks in advance.

Here is the exception's StackTrace, maybe there is something important.

`StackTrace at Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator, ComponentResourceLocation componentResourceLocation)\r\n   at AppName.Views.TracePage.InitializeComponent() in c:\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\AppName\\obj\\x86\\Debug\\Views\\TracePage.g.i.cs:line 44\r\n   at AppName.Views.TracePage..ctor() in c:\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\AppName\\Views\\TracePage.xaml.cs:line 26\r\n   at AppName.AppName_XamlTypeInfo.XamlTypeInfoProvider.Activate_40_TracePage() in c:\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\AppName\\obj\\x86\\Debug\\XamlTypeInfo.g.cs:line 177\r\n   at AppName.AppName_XamlTypeInfo.XamlUserType.ActivateInstance() in c:\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\AppName\\obj\\x86\\Debug\\XamlTypeInfo.g.cs:line 3698"   string`

Comment: Is there any inner exception by any chance? Like a `TypeInitializationException` or anything like that?

Comment: @Nate, no, the only exception i've got is this XamlParseException. I've added a StackTrace to my first post, maybe there is something important and i didn't notice it.

Comment: Would you trying when debugging, checking out the Locals at that point and seeing what Type the component is? That will be the beggest help I think. Otherwise, you can check `c:\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\AppName\\obj\\x86\\Debug\\XamlTypeInfo.g.cs:line 3698"` to find out what the object is.

Comment: Line 3698 contains this:
`override public object ActivateInstance()
{
    return Activator(); 
}`  
And the Activator is a type `System.Activator`

Comment: AH, then that's not where to look. The best thing to do would be to debug and traverse the stack trace, looking for the type that the activator is trying to create. That's where the error will be (in the type, that is).